# java android getClass

Tags: java, android

```
Class<?> b1;
b1 = GS.scr_check_freebox(x, y-GS.ss, this);

if ( b1.getClass().equals(BLK.class) || b1.getClass().equals(STN.class) )
{
    if (b1.falling == true)
    {
        scr_cascade_fall(scr_check_freebox(x, y-GS.ss, this));
        return (true);
    }
}
```

The function "scr_get_freebox" searches through all instances of BLK and STN and returns the first one it finds that exists wholly or partially inside a box with upper-left corner of the coordinate you pass it, but it will exclude from it's search the "this" that you pass it. It's not really important except that it returns either null or an instance of BLK or an instance of STN.

Giving error on line 5 where is says "if (b1.falling == true)"
The thing is, both those classes (BLK and STN) have a boolean variable called falling. The compiler is just being dumb here.

How do i get rid of this error? Is there a special way to use getClass() or instanceof ?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `b1` as `Class<?>`. So of course `b1.falling == true` is an compilation error as `Class<?>` doesn't have a `falling` field.

What you want is to change `Class<?> b1;` to a super class of `BLK`/`STN` so it can hold an instance of those classes, in worst case, if there is no other superclass than `Object` (and later using casts to access fields):

```
Object b1;
```

Comment: and how do you cast one object as another?

Comment: `MyObject mo = (MyObject) obj;`

Comment: i need a replacement example that uses Object because I casted b1 as BLK or STN depending on which class it came out, and the b1.falling still gives an error.